# Extend Gradle task written in Groovy with Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, gradle, groovy

In order to proceed a migration from Groovy/Java to Kotlin for a Gradle project, I would like to convert a Groovy class to Kotlin. My class extends another Groovy class with an implicit `implements GroovyObject`.

When using Java, this is not a problem, but Kotlin complains about abstract methods from `GroovyObject` that have to be implemented.

There is an [existing discussion](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/extending-groovy-class-from-kotlin/1675) but the solution does not work for me since I cannot call the abstract methods directly.

Comment: Please provide a full question (with code, no screenshots). The link of your crosspost might go away in the future and render this question useless.